# Java stream: limit doesnt work with Random().ints().sorted()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following code:

```
new Random().ints()
            .map(i -> i / 2)
            .limit(100)
            .toArray()
```

...and it works as expected.

But this doesn't work:

```
new Random().ints()
            .sorted()
            .map(i -> i / 2)
            .limit(100)
            .toArray()
```

It throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream size exceeds max array size
```

Shouldn't limit shortcircuit the stream and help in restricting it to 100 elements?

Comment: As the answer below shows, streams are a pipeline, and the operations you specify happen in-order. While it's true that streams will only operate on the elements that are needed, if you have an infinite stream, you will have to sort an infinite number of elements. Limiting before sorting will solve this problem. Also note `#sorted` is a [stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), `stateful` in this case meaning the entire stream must be processed before continuing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call `new Random().ints()` returns an infinite stream of pseudo random numbers. When you sort that, it internally uses an array. However, the max size of an array is obviously less than ∞. To fix the issue, use `limit` and make your stream finite first and then perform the sorting. In fact, this optimizes away the stream processing pipeline since you are sorting only necessary elements. Here's how it looks.

```
new Random().ints().limit(100).map(i -> i / 2).sorted().toArray();
```

**Update**

As per the suggestion made in the below comment, you can further improve it like so.

```
new Random().ints(100).map(i -> i / 2).sorted().toArray();
```

The `ints` procedure produces a stream with exactly 100 pseudo random numbers and with that you can merely dispense with the `limit`. Moreover, the latter approach is a bit more succinct than the former.

Comment: It’s simpler and more efficient not to use `limit` but create a sized stream in the first place, `new Random().ints(100).map(i -> i / 2).sorted().toArray();`